# Why doesn't Ctrl+Alt+5 (insert € symbol) work?

Tags: windows, keyboard, shortcuts, europe

My laptop has a euro sign on the '5-key'. However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + 5</kbd> no euro symbol is inserted. What could be the cause of this?

OS: Windows 7.

Region setting: Dutch

Keyboard layout: US

Comment: Alt + 0128 should work ...

Comment: I can't get mine to work either :/ I tried a dutch keyboard layout as well (my laptop was bought in Holland).

Comment: You need Keyboard layout: *US-International*

Comment: @JosefZ Ok thanks, but the US International layout has dead keys which I really hate. Any solution?

Comment: Does AltGr+e give you an € ? (=Swedish keyboard layout, +SHIFT => ¢ )  Which key that generates a specific glyph is in software only.

Comment: I have the same.. but I use the open source tool espanso to have a shortcut for the Euro sign. Now, when I type .ee this is transformed to €.

Answer (score 4):

Windows doesn't have a proper keyboard layout for this, unless you use a Windows US International (then you can use the [right-alt]+[5]. The problem is that every time you want to type an ', `, " and so on, you'll have to enter a space or it'll try to put some accents on the following character.
You can also install the normal and international keyboard and switch between the layouts when needed.

If you opt to use Linux as a free alternative to Windows, you can install a normal US keyboard layout with the € symbol on 5, without any other inconveniences. They've had this for years and I still don't understand why Microsoft is still being so fussy about it. There are A LOT OF Belgian and Dutch users facing this problem.

If I had some programming skills, I'd create the layout myself because it's bloody annoying! It doesn't matter which version of Windows you're running, they all face the same problem.

Comment: On linux and "[right-alt]+[5]" is certainly not working for me.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367384/how-do-i-enter-the-euro-symbol, but you can easily choose a € symbol by using that keyboard combo when choosing the correct layout: US(euro on 5) or US International (if you also need access to accents, umlauts, cedilles, eszett, etc). Note that not all Linux distros come with this layout out of the box, so you might need to do some research on how to install this layout.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get the 5 key to work for the € symbol either.  CTRL ALT E works in Word but nowhere else.  The only thing that works consistently is ALT +0128.  A bit maddening.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.